# Use array[] datatype in QGIS from PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgresql, array

I'm just a beginner in GIS, so I'll be glad to see any comment here.

I have tables in PostgreSQL which I've connected to QGIS. There are columns in tables with datatype `array[]`. But it's not easy for users to insert data into column using such view as {a,d,c}. Is there an easy way to edit the data?

I have just some idea to put data in QGIS like 'a,b,c' and make a `trigger` on INSERT/UPDATE BEFORE which will put data into `Postgres` table in right look. But it also seems not the best way.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I'm aware of is kind of a 'per-use kludge'.

For example I have data that includes an array of property numbers (attribute name `propnum_array`, dtype `varchar[]`), and I sometimes want to identify any data where the array is empty.

Testing for `propnum_array = {}` or  `propnum_array is null` or `propnum[0]=''` (or any other variations on that type of theme) makes QGIS gag, however I can do   `regexp_match( propnum_array,'\\d')` or `propnum_array ilike '{""}'` or  `propnum_array = '{""}'` and partition the data into stuff that has non-empty `propnum_array` and stuff that hasn't.

What this means is that if the arrays have structure (e.g., specific values at specific elements in the array), you can scan for those: if you want all values where the second element in a 3-element array is 'Y', then you'll want something like `regexp_match( propnum_array,'[,]*\'Y\'\[,]*')` (pretty sure you have to escape the commas and single-quotes internal to the match string, but that a use-case for someone else to worry about).

The fact that `propnum_array ilike '{""}'` works, seems to indicate that QGIS treats arrays as if they're text. Alternatively, it might cast them to text on-the-fly, if required - but then it would not make sense for array types to be undocumented (AFAIK). I haven't been able to find any docs on array handling, and there are questions on the osgeo-qgis mailing list as recently as Jan 2015.

I guess the major hint is that there are no array functions in the expressions editor, although I understand that the ['Data Driven Input Mask'](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DataDrivenInputMask/) plugin has had array handling since v1.0.0 (Feb 2015).